# How to build a k ary tree with array implementation in C?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, tree

I'm working on an university project about k ary trees in C language. The exercise require to build a k ary tree as list and port it into an array. At the moment I can build the k ary tree as list successfully, now I'm trying to build a k ary tree with array implementation.

Note that the structure of my k ary tree is made up by one child and "k" siblings.
FOr example:

```
4 (root)
.
.
5---6---23---98
    .
    .
    78---53---22---19
```

So, about array implementation of a k ary tree, I'm thinking to use something like:

```
typedef struct {
      int value;
      int children[MAX];
} Karyarray;

Karyarray array[MAX];
```

...but I don't know how to store eventually child (and siblings) that has a previous child as parent. I hope I've been clear. So, do you have a best approach to implement a k ary tree with array? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you just trying to traverse the tree and putting every element into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't do the same as you would do normally with binary trees, in the node structures place a pointer to each of its children, the only differences is that now you have k children instead of two, so easiest way could be to store all children pointer in an array of pointers:

```
 struct treeNode {
   int              value;
   struct treenode *children[K];
 };
```

So to move into the i-th child you would do:

```
 child = parent->children[i];
```